# Can we auto-implement corrections based on the ATC results?

Tags: automation, abap

When we run the ATC over the code, it displays the results and changes/suggestions that needed to be done in the code,
if the system can tell you what needed to be changed, then can we automate the process of corrections?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Check below projects:

- [GitHub Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/)
- [Abapgit downport](https://github.com/abapGit/downport)